# Hide a <li> on a certain mobile resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I hide a `li` in mobile resolution? when width resolution < 600 (for example: ) hide items whith `class="txt-menu"`

My html:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">TITLE MENU</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="my-image_instead_of_menu-text"></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="txt-menu">my text intead of menu image</li><br>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `$(".txt-menu").hide();`

Comment: What's the "mobile resolution" you are aiming for? Phones/Tablets?

Answer (score 2):

Using [media queries](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/04/23/responsive-web-design-layouts-and-media-queries/) will solve your problem.

For mobile resolution you could use this piece of code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 599px) { 
    .txt-menu {
       display:none; 
    }
```

Also; take a look at [responsive design.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JavaScript for this per se. You can limit your styles to only apply on certain environment properties;

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 700px)
    li.text-menu {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery's [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) method to hide any HTML element. But From what I understand you basically want to change the menu type if a person access a page from a mobile. If that's the case instead of changing stuff manually you should consider looking at some responsive CSS frameworks.

Example:

1. [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)
2. [Gumby](http://gumbyframework.com/)
3. [Responsive Grid System](http://responsive.gs/)

If you'd still want to take a different route and puit more work on your shoulders you can use the following to detect a Mobile Device and then do stuff accordingly.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    /* Hide LI's here */
}
```

Here is a [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/jGWtC/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use only css to check mobile resolution and hide `<a>`:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
   li a.txt-menu{display:none;}
}
```